# Private database usage limit per application in cloudkit

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I am new to ios development. I am developing an application, where I need to store user's data. I am planning to user private database of cloudkit to store the data. Private database use is counted against the individual user's quota (Individual user gets 5GB of storage free) I want to know that is there any limit per application to use that free space? I mean how much of that 5GB data I can use for my application?

Thanks in advance,

Krishna

Comment: What type of data you need to store ? is it only Text or media files also? Also why do you want to use cloudkit? Just use CoreData or Sqlite for storing user's data.

Comment: Thanks Paras for your reply. I want to store text and media files also. And I want to take backup of user's data, that is why planning to use cloudkit.

Comment: Check this - https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/